# how to query some people in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

in facebook homepage ,after i login in ,i can serarch some people,restaurant an return result.

i search wang.song then it return wang.song page

i want to development it

i use [graph](https://graph.facebook.com/graph.facebook.com/search?q=wang.song&type=user&access_token=mytestusertoket)

but it return

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: graph.facebook.com",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

why? or grap can't suport search some people?

but i have new question

i want search result same with facebook homepage:
for example i search

Wang Liánhuā Yao
facebook homepage give me one person result
but i search with facebook api differen with facebook homepage
i search step
first:

get accestoken

parameter
installed:true
name:Foo Phpunit User
locale:zh_TW
permissions:read_stream,user_photos,user_likes,manage_pages"
i get one token

url:https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/myappid/accounts/test-users

two to query:
 q:Wang Liánhuā Yao
 type:user or page

this can not search any result from mainpage

q:阿牛牛肉麵
type:page
this search many other result

search result different with the mainpage

Comment: Use put `graph.facebook.com` twice into your link – as the host name, and then as the first path segment (where it doesn’t belong, and that’s why you get the message that `graph.facebook.com` is not an existing alias.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

For example, you can search users by name with the following API endpoint:

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=someusername&type=user
```

Keep in mind that you need a User Access Token for that, so you need to authorize a User first. Also, Users can deactivate search afaik, so not all of them will show up.

Comment: this can not search people

Comment: it can search people. that´s what "type=user" is for. and of course you have to urlencode your search string. please post exactly which api call you are trying to do.

Comment: is some error daisy chen url_encode is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?q=Daisy%20Chen&type=user&access_token=mytoken is can not get any info but facebook home page can get info

Comment: "some error"? well, it works fine for me, just tried it in the api explorer.